# Can a Dishwasher be installed underneath a Fuse Box?

Tags: code-compliance, dishwasher

Can a Dishwasher be installed underneath a Fuse Box? I have a cabinet in my Kitchen that I want to remove and put a dishwasher in place, but is this against code? I live in New Jersey, USA.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. How high is the fuse box on the wall? Will there be a counter between the dishwasher and the fuse box? (And, a picture would be helpful here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Nope, and that cabinet needs to go too

Whoever installed that fuse box was completely ignorant of NEC 110.26's clear working space rules.  In short, there's a 2.5' wide by 3' deep by 6.5' high box, directly in front of the electrical equipment (fuse box in your case), that *must* be kept clear to allow service access to it -- no appliances, no cabinets, no shelving units, no garbage cans, no boxes, no dollhouses, *nothing*.

Comment: now you know in those garages and basements what people do ...block that empty space with a nice cabinet, workbench or whatever we can find to fit in the empty space..it is empty space and as a nod to George Carlin I need to buy more stuff to put in that space - until I have no space and need to buy a bigger house with more space.. :-)